# Problems with importing Python packages after switching to OS X El Capitan?

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-elcapitan

I have already been using flask for a while and up until now have never had any problems. I know how to activate the virtualenv and I know that you must pip install any other modules inside the virtualenv. But suddenly my virtualenv has decided that flask is not a module and thus won't run my code. The only thing I can think of that has changed on my computer is that I have upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan. 
Could this be the cause of my broken venv?

For more detail, here's step by step what I'm doing.

First I'm opening the project folder:

```
cd project_folder
```

Then I'm creating the virtualenv folder (although it already exists, I always do this):

```
virtualenv venv
```

Then I activate it:

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

And now I see:

```
>>> (venv) My-Mac-Book: username$
```

Now I cd into the flask folder where my actual python code is.

Note: I'm using Python3. Also, I have never had a problem with this before.

```
cd flask
```

Then I try to run my code, which again, I have run many times without problems before switching to El Capitan.

```
 >>> (venv) My-Mac-Book:flask username$ python 1run_site.py
```

And rather than running as it always has, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1run_site.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect
ImportError: No module named flask
```

But when I try to do a pip install of flask, it tells me that I already have it.

```
pip install flask
```

Returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
```

Can anyone help me out here? 
I've heard that there have been some changes to the python path in El Capitan, but honestly I'm not familiar with 'PYTHONPATH' as I've seen in some other posts. Most other posts about flask are also made by people who haven't activated the virtualenv, but I have done this. 
 
Also if I open another terminal and run python normally, I am able to import flask without any errors, so I know that something must be upsetting it in the virtualenv.  
But again, I haven't touched anything on my computer besides upgrading to El Capitan and my python code for flask has been working fine for weeks.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try rolling back to the prior iOS version to see if your code works again, then you will be certain the upgrade is the culprit

Comment: @dinotom hey there! I'm trying to look up guides to do that but honestly can't find one that's simple enough for me to follow. I also don't have time machine set up, so I guess I need to do that before I can roll back. I'll order a hard drive now and definitely try to go back within the next few days :'(

Comment: Try this...http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/delete-el-capitan-go-back-to-yosemite-3581872/

Comment: will do, thanks! I'll check back in after I get my external hard drive in the mail! I really hope this is the problem.